# Password Regex Validation: Preventing Spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to adhere to the following password rule:

> Must be 6 to 15 characters, include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and at least one number. It should also contain no spaces.

Now, for everything but the spaces, I've got:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{6,15}$
```

Problem is, that allows spaces.

After looking around, I've tried using `\s`, but that messes up my lowercase and uppercase requirements. I also seen another suggestion to replace the `*` with a `+`, but that seemed to break the entire thing.

**To clarify, this is a client requirement unfortunately, I'm never usually this strict with passwords.**

Comment: Can your passwords start with a digit?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah I don't see that being a problem

Comment: Can't you just chuck in a bit of `if(s.Contains(" "))`? I hate using regex unless it is for searching

Comment: Why, why, why would you want to ban spaces in a password? Just don't do it. Allow passwords to be as long as possible and allow all characters. Anything else is just daft.

Comment: @mattytommo: Fair enough, that makes sense

Comment: @DavidArno It's a requirement from a client I'm afraid.

Comment: Then tell your client their requirement is bad. As a professional developer you have a responsibility to behave in a professional way and that includes saying "no" when necessary.

Comment: @DavidArno We're talking about a MAJOR client here, they can have whatever they want. I don't think is an earth shattering request, so no need to decline.

Comment: @DavidArno: A professional also has to take other things into consideration and strike a workable balance when necessary.  The client may be responding to requirements of one of *their* clients, vendors, regulatory needs, etc.  A professional doesn't just say, "I'm right, you're wrong, I refuse to do this."  A professional says, "This is what I recommend, and here's why I recommend it.  Let's find a solution that best fits your business needs."

Comment: @David Let me elaborate, the client already has a system that we're sending these credentials to. If they don't match, we'll get an exception through the API. Rather than wrapping this in a try catch It'd be better to validate **before** being sent.

Comment: @mattytommo: Fair enough, which I'd put into the "vendor" category in my comment.  The client has a legacy system, the replacement of which is probably well outside budget and scope at this time.  So, for clear business reasons, the new features must work with the legacy system.  It's a small hit to security standards, but that hit was *already incurred* and is not your doing, so I see no harm done here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)\S{6,15}$
```

`\S` stands for any NON space character.